# Android - Get location ( Geocoder / Google Play Service )?

Tags: android, geolocation, google-play-services, geocoding

I want to get the position of a user in terms of `city, address - latitude longitude`.
I have seen that there is a possibility of doing this using Google Play Service and Geocoder. Is that right?
Which method do you prefer and why?

With the Google Play service, it looks much easier to implement.
Is there anything I need to put into consideration?

Answer (score 1):

You can read the full documentation on [how to display a location address in android](https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address) that contains the latitude and longitude coordinates.

> Using the
>   [`Geocoder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder)
>   class in the Android framework location API's, you can convert an
>   address to the corresponding geographic coordinates.  You can use
>   [`getFromLocation()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder#getFromLocation(double,%20double,%20int))
>   method to convert a geographic location to an address. This method
>   returns an estimated street address corresponding to a given latitude
>   and longitude.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the methods below to get users' current location coordinates and location details.

```
 //Get last known location coordinates
    private void getLastLocationNewMethod() {
        FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getApplicationContext());
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            //session.saveCurrentLocation("Everywhere");
            return;
        }
        mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                // GPS location can be null if GPS is switched off
                if (location != null) {
                    double myLat = location.getLatitude();
                    double myLon = location.getLongitude();

                    getAddress(myLat, myLon);


                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.d("MapDemoActivity", "Error trying to get last GPS location");
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        });
    }

    //get location name from coordinates
    public void getAddress(double lat, double lng) {
        String currentLocation = "";

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.ENGLISH);
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
            Address obj = addresses.get(0);
            String add = obj.getAddressLine(0);
            add = add + "\n" + obj.getCountryName();
            add = add + "\n" + obj.getCountryCode();
            add = add + "\n" + obj.getAdminArea();
            add = add + "\n" + obj.getPostalCode();
            add = add + "\n" + obj.getSubAdminArea();
            add = add + "\n" + obj.getLocality();
            add = add + "\n" + obj.getSubThoroughfare();

            Log.v("IGA", "Address" + add);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```